# Snort rule for Javascript detection

Tags: javascript, rules, snort

I have a few Snort rules to signal an alert when a JS file is being downloaded from a web page, however none of them are triggering. I'm not quite sure of the details of writing snort rules, so these were some guesses pooled from various readings.

Not sure if having gzip encoded JS files makes a huge difference, but I did check my snort.conf file and it does contain the following options under

```
preprocessor http_inspect_server: server default \ 
.....
extended_response_inspection \
inspect_gzip \
normalize_utf \
unlimited_decompress \
normalize_javascript \
```

None of the 3 alerts below trigger even though the JS files contain the word "function", and the html file contains js with the following words "snort team!"

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"JS-Detect1"; file_data; content:"function"; sid:1000000)
alert tcp $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (file_data; content:"snort team!"; nocase; msg:"JS-Detect2"; sid:1000001)
alert tcp $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (file_data;content:"<script>"; nocase; msg:"JS-Detect3"; sid:1000002)
```

The following alert is triggering which is contained in the same rule file.

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"JS-Detect4"; sid:1000003)
```

Any advice or help for writing a snort rule that will trigger an alert when downloading a JS file, or necessary modifications to the snort.conf would be be of great help! Thanks.

Comment: try this: alert tcp $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (file_data;content:"<script"; nocase; msg:"JS-Detect3"; sid:1000002)

Comment: tried it without the ">" at end of script but unfortunately that didn't trigger either.

Comment: Just to verify, this isn't https traffic that you're trying to inspect is it? This is port 80 http traffic?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: My issue was resolved when  I turned off gro using "sudo ethtool -K eth1 gro off" and removed "file_data" as an option.

Comment: you can also do it with regex more information here: http://manual.snort.org/node32.html#SECTION00451200000000000000